# sympy solve unable to find roots

Tags: sympy

sympy does not find the two real roots of this rather straightforward equation:

```
import sympy
x = Symbol('x')
solve(-2*x**2*exp(1 - x**2) + exp(1 - x**2),x)
```

Returns "[oo]"

Is this a bug or is my command ill formed ?

Thanks!

Markus

Comment: What version of sympy are you using? It seems to work in `0.7.2`. Offtopic: this can be solved easily on paper (just cancel `exp`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful answer. I am using sympy indirectly via the R package rSymPy, which migth be using a Version below 0.7.2. I will attempt to upgrade then.
Yes, this problem is easily done by hand but I am trying to automate the Generation of homework problems.

Comment: That's not the case here, but in general be sure the free variable domain doesn't prevent finding a valid root, e.g. if the free variable is defined with `integer=True` and the roots are not integers. Also be sure the solver is not restricted to some non-compatible domain.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me, so perhaps you just need to upgrade?

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol, solve, exp
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> solve(-2*x**2*exp(1 - x**2) + exp(1 - x**2),x)
[-sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2]
>>> sympy.__version__
'0.7.2-git'
```